# get count and sum in same column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have below mentioned dataframe in R.

```
ID       Date         Type         Value
K-1      2018-01-01   A            4
K-2      2018-01-01   B            7
K-3      2018-01-01   C            12
K-4      2018-01-02   A            6
K-5      2018-01-02   A            4
K-6      2018-01-02   B            15
K-7      2018-01-02   B            10
```

I want to learn how to convert the dataframe in below given required dataframe, Where `A`, `B` and `C` should be static for every date, irrespective of if that particular type is available or not on that date.

In addition, I want to count the `ID` group by date and `Type`, in the bucket of `<5` ( If Value is between 1-4), `5-10` (if value is between 5 to 10) and `>10` (if value is higher than 10).

`sum` column should consist of the total of value for that particular date and Type as well.

`Count` column should consist of the count of `ID` group by particular date and `Type`.

The bucket `<5`,`5-10` and `>10` should always be there in required output, irrespective if value available for that bucket or not.

In addition, how to get sum of particular `ID` group by their bucket in bracket `()` with comma separated 2 decimal value.
The font of sum in bracket should be smaller than the font of count (i.e if the font of count for `<5` bucket is 12 than the font of sum in bracket should be 10).
Also, If the count in particular bucket is 0 than there is no need of bracket with (0.00) as value.

Required DF

```
Date           Count      <5      5-10       >10      sum
2018-01-01      3         1 (4)    1 (7)      1 (12)   23
A               1         1 (4)    0          0        4
B               1         0        1 (7)      0        7
C               1         0        0          1 (12)   12
2018-01-02      4         1 (4)    2 (16)     1 (15)   35
A               2         1 (4)    1 (6)      0        10
B               2         0        1 (10)     1 (15)   25
C               0         0        0          0        0
```

The Code I'm using (from SO):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Result = case_when(
    Value < 5                        ~"<5",
    Value >= 5 & Value <= 10         ~"5-10",
    Value > 10                       ~">10"
  )) %>%
  group_by(Date, Type, Result) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(Value)) %>%
  mutate(Flag = 1L) %>%
  spread(Result, Flag, fill = 0L) %>%
  group_by(Date, Type) %>%
  summarize_all(list(~sum(.))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(Date, Type)

dat2[is.na(dat2)] <- 0

dat3 <- dat2 %>% mutate(Count = rowSums(select(., -Date, -Type, -sum)))

dat4 <- dat3 %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(-Type), list(~sum(.))) 

dat_final <- map2_dfr(split(dat4, f = dat4$Date),
                      split(dat3, f = dat3$Date),
                      ~bind_rows(.x %>% rename(Type = Date), 
                                 .y %>% select(-Date)))

dat_final2 <- dat_final %>%
  select(Date = Type, Count, `<5`, `5-10`, `>10`, sum)
dat_final2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tables package is good for compactly describing such output.  First create functions that compute the statistics shown in the columns.  Then use the indicated `tabular` formula.  The LHS is the rows and the RHS is the columns.  + means concatenate the variables described on either side of the +.

The output of the `sprintf` can be varied by, for example, changing the format string. See `?sprintf` .

### latex

Also if `tab` is the output of the `tabular` command then `latex(tab)` will create a latex version and you can vary it further by inserting latex commands. For example  `"%d \\tiny{(%d)}"` as the `sprintf` format string will make the parenthesized portion smaller in the latex output.

### html

If you want `html` output then with `tab` as just defined then `html(tab)` creates an html version that can be varied further with appropriate html taggs.  For example `"%d <small>(%d)</small>"`  as the `sprintf` format string will make the parenthesized portion smaller in the html output.

### input

We provide the input `dat` in reproducible form in the Note at the end. Next time please ensure that the input is provided in reproducible form.

### code

This mostly reproduces the output shown in the question and is much more compact than the code there.

```
library(tables)

outstring <- function(x) if (length(x)) sprintf("%d (%d)", length(x), sum(x)) else 0
`<5` <- function(x) outstring(x[x < 5])
`5-10` <- function(x) outstring(x[x >= 5 & x <= 10])
`>10` <- function(x) outstring(x[x > 10])

tab <- 
  tabular(Date * (1 + Type) ~ (n=1) + Value * (`<5` + `5-10` + `>10` + sum), data = dat)
```

giving:

```
                       Value                  
 Date                n <5    5-10   >10    sum
 2018-01-01      All 3 1 (4) 1 (7)  1 (12) 23 
            Type A   1 1 (4) 0      0       4 
                 B   1 0     1 (7)  0       7 
                 C   1 0     0      1 (12) 12 
 2018-01-02      All 4 1 (4) 2 (16) 1 (15) 35 
            Type A   2 1 (4) 1 (6)  0      10 
                 B   2 0     1 (10) 1 (15) 25 
                 C   0 0     0      0       0
```

### Note

```
dat <- 
structure(list(ID = structure(1:7, .Label = c("K-1", "K-2", "K-3", 
"K-4", "K-5", "K-6", "K-7"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02"
), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Value = c(4L, 
7L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 15L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

### Update

The `tabular` class has an as.matrix method and we can perform simple manipulations on that to produce the following output:

```
m <- as.matrix(tab)
m2 <- cbind(paste0(m[, 1], sub("All", "", m[, 3])), m[, -(1:3)])[-1, ]
setNames(as.data.frame(m2[-1, ]), m2[1, ])
```

giving:

```
        Date n    <5   5-10    >10 sum
1 2018-01-01 3 1 (4)  1 (7) 1 (12)  23
2          A 1 1 (4)      0      0   4
3          B 1     0  1 (7)      0   7
4          C 1     0      0 1 (12)  12
5 2018-01-02 4 1 (4) 2 (16) 1 (15)  35
6          A 2 1 (4)  1 (6)      0  10
7          B 2     0 1 (10) 1 (15)  25
8          C 0     0      0      0   0
```

Comment: Getting error `Error in term2table(rows[[i]], cols[[j]], data, n) : 
  Duplicate values: Date and Value`.

Comment: @user9211845  Not able to reproduce the error with `dat` in the answer.  You may need to show the `dput` of  a small example that caused the error

Comment: @G.Grothendieck : Still getting the same error, Here is the dput of my dataframe `structure(list(ID = c("CRX-1234", "CRX-4567", "CRX-1011"
), Date = c("2019-04-01", "2019-04-01", "2019-04-01"), Type = c("A", 
"B", "C"), Value = c(190000, 230000, 1110000
)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", " Type ", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: It worked but not converting into dataframe `cannot coerce class ""tabular"" to a data.frame`.

Comment: @akrun: I have provided the `dput` in the thread, the output is not coming in a desired format.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: I have already tried that method but the output is not coming in desired format, I have mentioned the `dput` in your answer for your reference.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: ok...I'll remove that from there.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: Thanks, I had some varialbe name like `A_Var` which change to `A\_Var`. How to remove that \ sing. I have tried `DF<-xcv$Date[xcv$Date == "A\_Var"] <- "A_Var"` but it didn't work.